# Pointer variable can't be given value, instead, normal variable can be

Tags: c, pointers, struct, init

I faced a wired problem, it is a big and commercial project so I can't put the original code here. but the logic is like this:

```
struct sample_t
{
  int inta;
  int * p_intb;
};
sample_t sample ={0};
sample.inta = 0; 
sample.p_intb = NULL; // crashed, why?
```

run into crash due to the pointer operation, but for `inta` there was no problem.
however,
if I use `memset(&sample.p_intb, 0, 4)` to replace above equal, it worked.

What is the reason of this? How to solve this problem?

[This is a screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68MDQ.png)

Comment: This code by itself it fine.  The problem is in the code you haven't shown.  Please update your question with a [mcve].  It should exhibit the same problem as your real code but in a condensed format.

Comment: The code is not valid C. Did you just miss a `struct` or is this really C++? But aside from that, there is nothing wrong with the shown code in either case and you probably have undeifned behavior somewhere else in your program. It does not need to be at the same location at which the problem manifests. General suggestions: Valgrind, ASAN, other sanitizers, etc.

Comment: it is quite difficult to make a reproducible example because of the complex arch of the project. I am suspecting that my problem is related to compiler, because the same code running on another platform is ok, but now on TC3x7, this problem happened.

Comment: That sounds like [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Run your full code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of code in your question, copy the source directly. And the code in the screenshot is quite different from the example: Any part left of the assignment operator `=` can trigger the crash. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem was caused by pointer start address(must be times of 4)
I am not sure about the exact reason, but should be related to the chip (ecu).

Comment: So you had a pointer to a `sample_t` that was misaligned, and that is not shown in the fake code posted in the question. That is why people are supposed to provide a [mre].